# Why Javascript has some functions in a way and some in another?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I've noticed in Javascript there are 2 different ways to use functions:

1. Use the variable followed by a dot and then the function, like `string.trim();`
2. Use the variable inside the function, like `parseInt(string)`

What are the differences?

Are the one in point #1 not functions? How are they called?

I know inside parenthesis you can have more variables, but why is `str.trim()` and not `trim(str)`?

Comment: Note that _technically_ `parseInt(string)` is actually `window.parseInt(string)` - ie it's still a function on a "variable", that happens to take an argument.

Comment: Also, since `parseInt` is mentioned here without using one, [_"Always specify a radix to avoid this unreliable behavior"_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Octal_interpretations_with_no_radix)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are both functions, but I believe the first example in your question is normally called a method.

I'd encourage you to read the really useful [Functions chapter of Eloquent Javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html). Just a couple of extracts that seem relevant:

> A function definition is just a regular variable definition where the
>   value given to the variable happens to be a function.

and

> A function is created by an expression that starts with the keyword
>   function. Functions have a set of parameters (in this case, only x)
>   and a body, which contains the statements that are to be executed when
>   the function is called. The function body must always be wrapped in
>   braces, even when it consists of only a single statement (as in the
>   previous example).
>
> A function can have multiple parameters or no parameters at all.

I would also keep in mind that in JS almost everything is an object, or as [someone else put it](http://www.maritimejournal.com/__data/assets/pdf_file/0020/1033940/Javascript-The-Good-Parts.pdf):

> Since functions are objects, they can be used like any other value.
>   Functions can be stored in variables, objects, and arrays. Functions
>   can be passed as arguments to functions, and functions can be returned
>   from functions. Also, since functions are objects, functions can have
>   methods